# Telegraf.js add buttons with markup on sendPhoto

Tags: node.js, telegraf, telegram-api, telegraf.js

I've a `bot.telegram.sendPhoto()` with this code:

```
bot.telegram.sendPhoto(
  channel_id,
  {source: filepath},
  { 
    caption: description.join("\n"), 
    parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2'
  }
)
```

(description is an array with some text.

So i would to add some buttons and then perform an action but how can i do?
I've tried in this way:

```
const buttons = Markup.keyboard([
            ["Test", "Test2"]
        ]).oneTime().resize().extra()
```

and then added it into the {...} after parse_mode:

```
{ 
  caption: description.join("\n"), 
  parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2',
  buttons
}
```

but it doesn't work.
And i tried also after the {...}

```
{ 
  caption: description.join("\n"), 
  parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2'
},
buttons
```

but it still doesn't work. So how can i do? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

`Markup.keyboard` represents custom-keyboard (see [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards)) for replying text - which can't possibly be used in channels (since members can't send messages in channels).

You probably are looking for [inline-keyboards](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating) (buttons that are attached at the bottom of messages members can interact with).

Here is how you send inline keyboard in telegraf (example with `callback_data` buttons):

```
const buttons = Telegraf.Extra.markup((m) =>
  m.inlineKeyboard([
      [ m.callbackButton('Test', 'test') ],
      [ m.callbackButton('Test 2', 'test2') ]
  ])
)

bot.action('test', async (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx)
  try {
    await ctx.answerCbQuery();    
  } catch (error) {
  }
})


bot.telegram.sendPhoto(
  channel_id,
  {source: filepath},
  { 
    caption: description.join("\n"), 
    parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2',
    reply_markup: buttons.reply_markup
  }
)

bot.launch()
```

If you want to use the `telegraf/markup` module instead, update the code as follows:

```
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup')

const buttons = Markup.inlineKeyboard([
  [Markup.callbackButton('Test', 'test')],
  [Markup.callbackButton('Test 2', 'test2')]
])

bot.telegram.sendPhoto(
  channel_id, {
    source: filepath
  }, {
    caption: description.join("\n"),
    parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2',
    reply_markup: buttons
  }
)
```

**sample output:**

[image]

**Further Resources:**

- [Telegram Documentation of inline keyboard markup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)
- [More detailed examples](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/af8aa6a3b23957166ba5c527bf72f4753c01eaa0/docs/examples/keyboard-bot.js).

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong. The sample output I've attached is the direct result of the sample code I've given. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63882563/edit) to add the snippet you've written, or share it via pastebin/Github Gist - so that I can help

Comment: no ok sorry my bad i forgot that i added something with the markup and i forgot to escape a dot. It works perfectly. But why it doesn't work if i do Markup.inlineKeyboards? (From require('telegraf/markup');?

Comment: I have added an example for you, please take a look at the updated answer